# Juno beta starting up really slow, times out on black screen >3min

Tags: display

On MBP 6,1 2010 Juno beta boots normally at first but then times out on a black screen for over 3min, 5min originally.

I've tried [this](https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/really-slow-boot-time.2222/) and it has significantly reduced the boot time, together with editing grub as follows :

vi /etc/default/grub

changing:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
to:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=SVIDEO-1:d"

However, compared to Loki that boots immediately, 3min boot time is too much. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to have been solved automatically by the recent system updates.